# workaround for 'reopen' terminal (to access newly installed stuff)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, shell, ubuntu-16.04

Ok so basically I'm writing a shell script which needs to install nvm and then use it.

Problem is, nvm requires that you close and reopen the terminal after installation.

So I wanted to know if there was a way that I can workaround this requirement?

I'm on ubuntu 16.04

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to  [this source](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/), the solution after installing `npm` is to run:

```
source ~/.profile
```

An equivalent but more portable command is:

```
. ~/.profile
```

#### More details

There are various initialization scripts that the shell might use, such as, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.profile`.  There are also system wide files, stored under `/etc`, that are used for initialization.  Apparently, the `npm` installation process is modifying one or more of them.  You might look at them to see if and how they were modified.  Any of the modified files can be sourced as above.